# NSOutlineView with 2 columns, text and check

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have done this :

That is NSOutlineView with two columns, first column is TextCell and on second column I drag and drop Check Box Cell.
Now, I set true all rows so :

```
-(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *) tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        return [item name];
    } else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"sel"]) {
        return @"1"; //for NSOnState
                //return @"0"; //for NSOffState
    }
}
```

Now I want that when user click on checkbox it go to NSOffState and I try inside method so :

```
-(void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {

    [item setSel:NSOffState];
}
```

but it don't go, how can i do ?

Help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #import 

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject  {
        NSMutableArray *array;
    }

    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

    @end
```

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;

    - (void)dealloc
    {
       [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    -(void)awakeFromNib
    {
        array=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
        NSMutableDictionary *dc=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        BOOL test=YES;
        NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithBool:test];

        [dc setObject:num forKey:@"sel"];
        [dc setObject:@"name" forKey:@"name"];

        [array addObject:dc];
    //[self setArray:self.array];
     }

     - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
     {
        return [array objectAtIndex:index];
     }


     - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
     {
        return NO;
     }

     - (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
     {
        return [array count];
     }

     - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn       *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
     {
        if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"])
     {
        /*
        NSString *str=[item objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"name=%@",str);*/
        return @"name"; //str;
     }
        else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"sel"])
       {
        /*
        NSString *str=[item objectForKey:@"sel"];
        NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithBool:[str boolValue]];
        NSLog(@"sel=%@",num);*/
        return @"0"; //num;
       }
     else
         {
         return nil;
         }
     }
     - (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView setObjectValue:(id)object    forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
     {
       [item setValue:object forKey:[tableColumn identifier]];
     }

     @end
```